# Why am i getting segmentation fault in deleting node?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault

```
    node * del(node * start,int loc)
{
    int l=len(start);
    if(loc<1 || loc>l)
    {
        printf("Deletion not possible. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(loc==1)
        {
            node *p;
            p=start;
            start=start->next;
            free(p);
        }
        else
        {
            node *p,*q;
            p=start;
            for(int i=1;i<=loc-1;i++)//check this one.
            {
                q=p;
                p=p->next;
            }
            q->next=p->next;
            free(p);
        }       
        printf("Deletion completed!\n");
    }
    return start;
}
```

This is the function and I am calling it from main() as:

```
case 5:
            printf("Enter the node you want to delete. \n");
            scanf("%d",temp);
            start=del(start,temp);
            break;
```

While deleting any node I am getting segmentation fault!I am stuck at this .
Can anyone help?

here is the full program:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node * next;
};

typedef struct Node node;

int len(node * start)
{
    if(start==NULL)
        return 0;
    int c=1;
    while(start!=NULL)
    {
        start=start->next;
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}
node * insert(node* start,int loc,int d)
{
    int l=len(start);
    node * p=start;
    node * temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(loc<1 || loc>l+1)
    {
        printf("Insertion not posible.!\n");
        return start;
    }       
    if(l==0 || loc==1)
    {
        temp->next=start;
        start=temp;
        temp->data=d;
        printf("Insertion completed.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=loc-2;i++)
        p=p->next;
        temp->next=p->next;
        p->next=temp;
        temp->data=d;
        printf("Insertion completed. \n");
    }   
    return start;
}
void show(node *start)
{
    int l=len(start);
    if(l==0)
    {
        printf("Nothing to print. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=1;i<l-1;i++)
        {
            printf(" %d -> ",start->data);
            start=start->next;
        }
        printf(" %d \n",start->data);
    }   
}
node * destroy(node * start)
{
    node * p=start;
    while(start!=NULL)
    {
        start=start->next;
        free(p);
        p=start;
    }
    printf("Destroy of linked list completed! .\n");
    return NULL;
}
node * del(node * start,int loc)
{
    int l=len(start);
    if(loc<1 || loc>l)
    {
        printf("Deletion not possible. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(loc==1)
        {
            node *p;
            p=start;
            start=start->next;
            free(p);
        }
        else
        {
            node *p,*q;
            p=start;
            for(int i=1;i<=loc-1;i++)//check this one.
            {
                q=p;
                p=p->next;
            }
            q->next=p->next;
            free(p);
        }       
        printf("Deletion completed!\n");
    }
    return start;
}
int main()
{
    node * start=NULL;
    int ch,temp,d;
    ch=temp=d=0;
    while(ch != -1)
    {
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 0:
            printf("Enter 0 to show menu.\n");
            printf("Enter 1 to create linked list.\n");
            printf("Enter 2 to destroy linked list.\n");
            printf("Enter 3 to get the length of likned list.\n");
            printf("Enter 4 to insert element in the linked list.\n");
            printf("Enter 5 to delete element from the linked list.\n");
            printf("Enter 6 to view the linked list.\n");
            printf("Enter 7 to reverse a linked list.\n");
            break;

            case 1:
            printf("Enter the size of link list to begin with.\n");
            scanf("%d",&temp);
            for(int i=1;i<=temp;i++)
            {
                printf("Enter the data to bes inserted to node %d .\n",i);
                scanf("%d",&d);
                start=insert(start,i,d); 
            }
            break;

            case 2:
            start=destroy(start);
            break;

            case 3:
            printf("Size of linked list is: %d \n",len(start));
            break;

            case 4:
            printf("Enter the location where you want to insert the data.\n");
            scanf("%d",&temp);
            printf("Enter the data to be intered.\n");
            scanf("%d",&d);
            start=insert(start,temp,d);
            break;

            case 5:
            printf("Enter the node you want to delete. \n");
            scanf("%d",temp);
            start=del(start,temp);
            break;

            case 6:
            show(start);
            break;

            default:
            ch=0;
            break;
        }
        printf("\nEnter your choice? \n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
    }
    destroy(start);


}
```

Comment: `if(loc<1 || loc>l)` ... you assert that the `loc` can only be one, but then you have an if-else after this which checks the value of `loc`.

Comment: I am checking there for wrong indexing!

Comment: I am checing whether the entered location is less than 1 and greater than length of linked list.

Comment: You are re-checking the same condition you already tested to decide whether to go down that branch at all. Fix that and like code, and maybe you'll find your error.

Comment: You may also benefit by searching this site for "C linked list" there are many many examples. You can even click on the "linked-list" tag and then "Newest" tab for a number of recent examples.

Comment: What len function has returned and which element are you deleting?

Comment: len returns the length of linked list and I am trying to delete any node entered by the user as loc

Comment: I'am asking about specific numbers in your case

Comment: Post full code, without that we can only guess

Comment: Did you use a debugger to find out which line causes the segfault, at least?

Comment: i have posted the complete code.

Comment: @immibis no i have done debugging on ide

Comment: `if(loc<1 || loc>l)` I am confident that you might be able to find an identifier that cannot be confused with a `1` easily.

Comment: That happened because I use different font in my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
    case 5:
    printf("Enter the node you want to delete. \n");
    scanf("%d",temp);
    start=del(start,temp);
    break;
```

line `scanf("%d",temp);` to `scanf("%d",&temp);`